# Who do I contact?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, ethics, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior

The company I work for holds a daily call to discuss candidates. These calls are increasingly becoming unprofessional due to candidates being evaluated on factors unrelated to the positions being sought for such as appearance - weight attractiveness among other factors.

Whom would I go to and discuss my concerns in regards to this unprofessional behavior?

Comment: For what role are the candidates being considered? For certain roles, appearances do matter.

Comment: @Goose, do you work in Human Resources? As you are privy to these conversations, it seems reasonable to infer that you do.

Comment: I am actually a Medical Sales Rep Manager on the west coast. The reps are calling on surgery center and hospitals to sell capital equipment. Appearance is insignificant in this role and experience and passion are vital.

Answer (score 1):

Protesting in the meeting would be the first step. The Hr department would be your next step. If that doesn't work, the legal department.

You may or may not want to start job-hunting first, in case this goes poorly.

Comment: Small company and HR and legal are actually part of the conversations. I have already given my notice but still feel it is up to me to report.

Comment: If you care enough to risk having trouble finding employment in the future, and you have other witnesses or hard evidence, the nuclear option would be to go to the media. How much are you willing to sacrifice in order to take a stand on this? Pick you battles and don't gamble more than you are willing to lose.

Comment: I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems reasonable to infer you work in Human Resources. Screening candidates and discussion of their qualifications in a call such as the one that you describe is often privy only to HR personnel.

**Hence, you should discuss with your departmental management. It is to their and the company's best interests to stop this behavior ASAP because it exposes the company to legal liability**